# Where to add a control variable in R function (cox hazard ratio)

Tags: r, function, cox-regression

I am using the below R function to generate a list of univariate hazard ratio results. However, I need to control for the 'job_site' location but am having trouble determining where to include it in the function code for it work properly. If I were to run it one at a time it would look like this:

uinvariate.cox <-coxph(Surv(breakthrough$person_time, breakthrough$n_result) ~ outpatient_settings
** + job_site**
, data = breakthrough)

Would you be able to assist me?
Thanks.

```
covariates <- c("outpatient_settings",
                "icu",
                "non_icu",
                "emergency_department",
                "sex")
              
univ_formulas <- sapply(covariates,
                        function(x) as.formula(paste('Surv(breakthrough$person_time, breakthrough$n_result)~', x)))

univ_models <- lapply( univ_formulas, function(x){coxph(x, data = breakthrough)})
# Extract data 
univ_results <- lapply(univ_models,
                       function(x){ 
                         x <- summary(x)
                         p.value<-signif(x$wald["pvalue"], digits=2)
                         wald.test<-signif(x$wald["test"], digits=2)
                         beta<-signif(x$coef[1], digits=2);#coeficient beta
                         HR <-signif(x$coef[2], digits=2);#exp(beta)
                         HR.confint.lower <- signif(x$conf.int[,"lower .95"], 2)
                         HR.confint.upper <- signif(x$conf.int[,"upper .95"],2)
                         HR <- paste0(HR, " (", 
                                      HR.confint.lower, "-", HR.confint.upper, ")")
                         res<-c(beta, HR, wald.test, p.value)
                         names(res)<-c("beta", "HR (95% CI for HR)", "wald.test", 
                                       "p.value")
                         return(res)
                         #return(exp(cbind(coef(x),confint(x))))
                       })
res <- t(as.data.frame(univ_results, check.names = TRUE))
as.data.frame(res)
```

univ_formulas <- sapply(covariates,
function(x) as.formula(paste('Surv(breakthrough$person_time, breakthrough$n_result)~**job_site+**', x)))

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 5

Comment: What is the exact mean of control variable? Do you want the `job_site` being used as a covariate in the Cox regression?

Comment: where exactly is your error occurring?  The `sapply()` call at the end of your post works without error.

Comment: Never use $-extraction inn formulas when using a data argument.